# Animate Addition/Removal of View in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, uiviewanimationtransition

I have created a bottom alert that I want to animate when it is to be presented or removed. Currently it is not doing any animation, only showing up and removing itself when needed.

I've tried using `.transition(.move(edge: .bottom))` on the actual view but no animation is shown.

How can I add a slide up/down animation for this view?

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            toolbar
            Spacer()
            switch viewModel.status {
            case .loading:
                LoadingView(isAnimating: $isLoading)
            case .loaded(_):
                productView
            case .error(_):
                Text("Please Retry.")
                    .onAppear {
                        buildBottomAlert(type: .error)
                    }
            }
        }
        
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            if let bottomView = bottomAlertView {
                bottomView
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
        }
        }
}
```

Bottom Alert Builder

```
func buildBottomAlert(type: BottomAlertType) {
    self.bottomAlertView = BottomAlert(type: type)
    self.showBottomAlert = true
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
        self.removeBottomAlert()
    }
}

func removeBottomAlert() {
    bottomAlertView = nil
    showBottomAlert = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For animation, you need to add your show/hide code inside body of [`withAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/withanimation(_:_:)) function.

```
withAnimation {
    buildBottomAlert(type: .error)
}
```

Also, update your `buildBottomAlert` function like this.

```
func buildBottomAlert(type: BottomAlertType) {
    self.bottomAlertView = BottomAlert(type: type)
    self.showBottomAlert = true
    Task {
        //Sleep for 2 seconds
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 2_000_000_000)
        withAnimation {
            removeBottomAlert()
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have used [`sleep(nanoseconds:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(nanoseconds:)) instead of [`asyncAfter(deadline:execute:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300020-asyncafter).